# How to compile Visual Studio 2019 release build with GLFW pre-compiled binaries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2019, glfw

I am attempting to build a program in Visual Studio 2019 that is using the GLFW pre-compiled static library (if it matters, it is for Vulkan and not OpenGL). When I build in debug mode, it compiles just fine. When I compile in release mode, I get the following errors:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie  [myapp] [project_path]\glfw3.lib(win32_joystick.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie  [myapp] [project_path]\glfw3.lib(wgl_context.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie  [myapp] [project_path]\glfw3.lib(egl_context.obj)   1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie  [myapp] [project_path]\glfw3.lib(osmesa_context.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie  [myapp] [project_path]\glfw3.lib(input.obj) 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie  [myapp] [project_path]\glfw3.lib(win32_init.obj)    1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie  [myapp] [project_path]\glfw3.lib(win32_monitor.obj) 1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __security_check_cookie  [myapp] [project_path]\glfw3.lib(context.obj)   1
```

and many more errors just like those relating to glfw.

I have already checked that:

a) both my debug and release configurations are configured exactly the same for linking to glfw.

b) the glfw3.lib file comes from the latest download of pre-compiled binaries in the lib-vc2019 folder.

c) They are the 64-bit binaries and both debug and release are building in 64-bit mode

Just for testing, I also tried the 32-bit binaries (obviously didn't work) and I also removed the library just to make sure both builds gave the same error message (they did)

The only glfw functions I use are

```
glfwInit()
glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions()
glfwCreateWindow()
glfwCreateWindowSurface()
glfwDestroyWindow()
glfwTerminate()
```

I'm guessing code is not the issue; but that it is caused by some compiler setting I don't know about that is different by default in the release configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Adrian's answer, I checked the other configurations in that category and found that the "Runtime Library" option under "C/C++ Code Generation" was the problem. In debug, it is set to "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" and in release it is set to "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)". After changing it to the debug DLL, the release build compiles and runs without issue.

This seems like a glfw bug, but for what it is changing this setting works

Comment: Glad it worked! However, using the `/MDd` build option when everything else is set to the "Release" options (e.g. `NDEBUG` is defined) can sometimes cause other problems down the line.

Comment: I would get on to the GLFW folks and let them know they've released a debug build.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the compiler "Security Check" option (most likely). In your project settings, go to those for C/C++ and "Code Generation," where you should select "Disable Security Check" or "Enable Security Check," whichever is the setting for the Debug configuration (which works).

But do check if this setting is different between your Debug and Release builds! I suspect you have to have the same setting selected as that used when the GLFW library was built.

Comment: Looks like both configurations are the same for that setting (it's set to Enable Security Check). In that same category though, Basic Runtime Checks, Runtime Library, and Enable Function-Level Linking have different options. Could any of those be the issue?